# Rails 3 prototype render :update response has text/html content-type

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, content-type, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get some RJS code written with prototype and Rails 2.3.11 to work in Rails 3.2.1

I have the `prototype-rails` gem, so `render :update do |page|` works, I'm using a form with `:remote => true` that sends an ajax request to the controller, and the javascript looks like it's being generated ok.

However, the content-type in the header of the response is `text/html; charset=utf-8`, which should be `text/javascript`.

In the controller I'm calling it like this:

```
render :update do |page|
    if @step.errors.empty?
        page.redirect_to how_to_path(@article.id)
    else
        page.replace_html 'add_step_form', :partial => 'how_to/add_step', :locals => {:step => @step, :altered => true}
    end
end
```

It seems to generate the `window.location.href...` and `Element.update...` code ok, but it isn't executing because the content-type is wrong.

Is there something that I might be doing wrong that could cause this? I need a solution that  will make rjs with prototype work. jQuery will probably be used in the future, but making that change right now isn't an option.

**update:**
I've tried a few other ways of writing the code, including specifying `:content_type => "text/javascript"` in `render`, wrapping it in a `respond_to` block with `format.js`, and rewriting it as `js.erb` file, but all still are returning with `text/html` as the content-type in the response header.

**update**
I sort of figured out how to get the expected behavior by adding `headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"` in the controller before `render`, but this doesn't really seem like the best way to do it if I have to add that explicitly before every RJS instance.  I'd like a cleaner solution if anyone can come up with one.

**update**
It turns out we had a `before_filter` running before every request that was setting the content-type to text/html. I removed this, and was able to remove all of the `headers["Content-Type"]` code that I added. It worked in my development environment but not in our testing verification environment. That turned out to be we had old assets cached on there, so verification was running prototype 1.6.1, while my local development environment had 1.7.0. That caused `rails.js` not to compile in verification, so all the requests had an `Accepts: text/html` instead of `text/javascript`. Flushing that cache loaded the newer version of prototype and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we had a before_filter that was being run before every request setting the content-type to text/html. I removed that, and it worked without the hack below.

But if you need a workaround, here's what I did below.

The only thing I figure out to make this work was to add `headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"` before the `render :update`

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"
render :update do |page|
  if @step.errors.empty?
    page.redirect_to how_to_path(@article.id)
  else
    page.replace_html 'add_step_form', :partial => 'how_to/add_step', :locals => {:step => @step, :altered => true}
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I've had to add it in every place in the code where the RJS `render :update` is called.

Comment: I'm marking this as the best answer. If somebody has a cleaner solution that I can verify, I'll gladly mark theirs instead.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't work in our testing verification environment, only in my local development environment, so unmarking best answer. Still need a way to fix it

Comment: Fixed it now. Turns out it wasn't the code, but an old `prototype.js` asset being cached in verification. Refreshing that allowed `rails.js` to compile correctly, and the client started requesting `text/javascript` instead of `text/html`