# How to redirect after a successful AJAX form submission (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose you have an edit form with `:remote => true`.  Your controller method looks like

```
 def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
            format.html { redirect_to @article}
            format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{article_path(@article)}');"}
        else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            # Render update.js.erb which replaces the body of the form
            format.js {}
        end
    end
end
```

What's the best way to do the redirect on successful article update in Rails 3.2.1?  The raw JS solution seems a little sleazy, but I do like the fact that it's obvious that it's performing the same function as the `format.html` version.

I would prefer a solution that does not use RJS ([if that even works in Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070350/rails-3-prototype-render-update-response-has-text-html-content-type)?)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the below line of code on the view file itself

```
#some_file.js.erb

`window.location = redirect_path
```

As you mentioned in the question you do not prefer RJS, but I think it's better to follow this pattern better than writing the js code in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ajax interact with a model (.php,.asp?). My preferred method in this instance is to create a success/fail criteria within the model after submission and redirect directly from there. Not sure if that makes sense in this application though?