# Redirect to after successful ajax form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a form with remote => true.
And right now my controller looks like:

```
  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = @store.items.build(params[:item])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_admin_item_path(@item), :flash => {:success => "#{@item.name} was successfully created."} }
        format.js { render :js => "window.location.href = ('#{edit_admin_item_path(@item)}');"}
        format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js { render :partial => 'fail_create.js.erb', :locals => { :ajax_errors => @item.errors.full_messages } }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }       
      end
    end
  end
```

Which works but feels very clumsy. It also doesn't allow me to use a flash notice, which is sad time indeed.

Ideally I feel like I should be able to simply use "format.js { redirect_to...} or check against the request headers and redirect_to. Sheesh!

I'm not sure what the best solution is. Any advice would be super awesome, thanks in advance!

-- PS -- I know this has been asked somewhat before but to no avail: [How to redirect after a successful AJAX form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506445/how-to-redirect-after-a-successful-ajax-form-submission-rails-3-2). There seems to many questions similar floating around, but no real solutions.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't the whole point of AJAX form submission that it *doesn't* require a page load? If you're going to redirect, might you not just as well do an old-fashioned submit?

Comment: The ajax is used to check validation and duplicate records. Then update the with an error message.

When the form is successful, I'm then wanting to redirect to the  edit_path. Which has image uploading and other stuff going on.

Comment: Right, but you can do JS form validation without AJAX submission. The only reason I know of to submit via AJAX is to avoid a page load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be impossible. The response to a Ajax request is processed by XMLHttpRequest. If a 3xx response is returned, XMLHttpRequest will follow the redirect itself, if the URL is of same origin. No matter how you set the headers, the browser cannot be aware of that. So the only way could be changing window.location with some Javascript.

Comment: Setting headers was what I was original wanted to be able to do. Seems like it can't be done!

Comment: Setting headers is not the Rails way; therefore, I would not recommend going that route.

Comment: So late here, I am currently using `make_resourceful` but unable to redirect the user to right place after `create` it goes to `show` always as it is not entering into `response_for(:create) do |format|` and goes out.
 any sample controller code? @AaronGray

Comment: @LearningROR sorry, I don't have any more apps using `make_resourceful`. I'd create a new question and see if you can get help that way. :)

Comment: @AaronGray. Thanks very much. Atleast your comment make more sense rather than no response from anyone. :)
My current question with no response is:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238691/unable-to-redirect-to-index-path-after-create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238691/unable-to-redirect-to-index-path-after-create). Any small app could also help me if you have one just code base with DRY controller and models only not whole project. :) I am in middle with my client right now. :(

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of [Rails responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) to generate my response messages and some content in my `<action>.js` file.

The content of — say `update.js` would look something like this:

```
// Checks if the article slug has changed.
// If it has the entire page should be reloaded at that new location.
<%= reload_if_slug_changed @article, params[:id] %>

// Displays the flash notices
// See ApplicationHelper#js_flash_response
<%= js_flash_response %>
```

Where the different methods are defined in some helper (in my case my ApplicationHelper). The content of the different methods are as follows:

```
def js_flash_response
  if flash.now[:notice].present?
    js = "$('#notice').html('#{flash.now[:notice]}').change();"
  elsif flash.now[:alert].present?
    js = "$('#alert').html('#{flash.now[:alert]}').change();"
  end
end

def reload_if_slug_changed object, expected_value
  "window.location.href = '#{url_for [:edit, object]}';" if object.slug != expected_value
end
```

The content of the flash messages are generated automatically by [Rails responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) and displayed with the `now` scope that deletes the from the flash hash, ensuring that if the user reloads (after the flash has been displayed) they will not reappear.

I don't believe that you should ever make a form pointing to a restful `create` action a remote one, because you would always expect critical redirect, so in my case I only need to redirect if the url slug has changed.

I hope that this helps. It's not a solution, but simply the way that I handled some of the same problems.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Under your scenario, here's how I would inject javascript into the page from a controller action.  After you've completed the logic section of your action insert something like this:

```
render :update do |page|
    page << "javascript_here"
end
```

This should allow you to insert you window.location or create a javascript flash method and call it when your create method executes correctly.

If you're looking to DRY up your controller actions, I would recommend looking into [this Railscast about make_resourceful](http://railscasts.com/episodes/92-make-resourceful).  Make_resourceful automagically performs each core activity for each action.  It also allows you to tap into the hooks that they've created such as `before :create`, `after :create`, `response_for :create`, and `after :create_fails`.  By using this gem, you can run code based on the success or failure of your methods and have finer grained control over them.

In addition to this, you should be able to initialize a create.js.erb and create_fails.js.erb in your view file, include a format.js without anything passed to it in your controller, and Rails will automagically run that file that contains javascript depending on if the controller action executed successfully.